# How to access "Headlines" and "Newsfeed" in FB AdCreative Marketing API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

In the Power Editor, while creating ad, (Traffic based campaigns), there is an option to edit "headlines" and "news feed link description" (Screenshot attached). I cannot find the corresponding fields in the Creative API.
I'm able to add the link and message though.

Here is a sample code:

```
link_data = AdCreativeLinkData()
link_data[AdCreativeLinkData.Field.message] = row['Message']
link_data[AdCreativeLinkData.Field.link] = row['Link']
link_data['Headline'] = row['Headline'] # <<<< NOT AVAILABLE
link_data['News Feed'] = row['News_feed'] # <<<< NOT AVAILABLE
link_data[AdCreativeLinkData.Field.image_hash] = img_hash

object_story_spec = AdCreativeObjectStorySpec()
object_story_spec[AdCreativeObjectStorySpec.Field.page_id] = config['page_id']
object_story_spec[AdCreativeObjectStorySpec.Field.link_data] = link_data

creative = AdCreative(parent_id=ad_account_id)
creative[AdCreative.Field.name] = 'AdCreative for Link Ad'
creative[AdCreative.Field.object_story_spec] = object_story_spec
creative.remote_create()

print(creative)
```

Any suggestions how to access the fields? Can it be done using curl?
[image: Power Editor for Ads]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following fields which affect headline and news feed:

```
    link_data[AdCreativeLinkData.Field.name] = "test headline"
    link_data[AdCreativeLinkData.Field.description] = "description test"
```